# Gephi Toolkit import miss edge/node

Tags: java, gephi

Gephi appears to be mis-importing simple weighted graphs. I have a graph like

```
graph G {
    1;
    2;
    3;
    1 -- 3 [ weight=1.0 ];
    3 -- 2 [ weight=1.0 ];
}
```

After importing, Gephi thinks I've added

```
 # Nodes loaded: 2
 # Edges loaded: 1
```

My code is:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.Container;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.ImportController;
import org.gephi.io.processor.plugin.DefaultProcessor;
import org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController;
import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
import org.openide.util.Lookup;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dot = "graph G {"
                + "1;"
                + "2;"
                + "3;"
                + "1 -- 3 [ weight=\"1.0\" ];"
                + "3 -- 2 [ weight=\"1.0\" ];"
                + "}";
        ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
        pc.newProject();
        Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

        ImportController importController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ImportController.class);

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(dot);
        Container container = null;
        container = importController.importFile(stringReader, importController.getFileImporter(".dot"));
        importController.process(container, new DefaultProcessor(), workspace);
    }

}
```

With unweighted graph importing is fine, with larger graph it also appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with Gephi 0.8.7 (and toolkit of the same version). The problem does not occur in Gephi 0.9.